# Python Tkinter: ¿Puedo hacer un evento/funcion que se actualize cada frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo una prueba en Tkinter mostrando la hora actualizada, para eso probe utilizando un `for` para ver si funcionaba. Lo puse antes del `.mainloop()` se ejecuto el `for` pero la ventana no, lo puse despues y ahora era al revés

Y ahora, intente con un while, y fue el mismo resultado depende donde lo colocaba

Codigo del while:

```
# UTILIZE LA LIBRERIA DATETIME !
while True:
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    timeText.config(text=("Bienvenido | " + str(time.strftime("%d")) + " 
    de " + 
    str(time.strftime("%h")) + ", " + str(time.strftime("%Y")) + " " + 
    str(time.strftime("%H")) + 
    ":" + str(time.strftime("%M"))))
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Hay alguna manera de hacer un "evento/funcion" que sea como un "update", osea que se actualize cada frame? ¿Como lo hago en Tkinter?

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

EDIT: Nuevo codigo que no ha funcionado tampoco (usando la funcion .after())

```
def updateTime():
    global timetext, timeText
    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    timetext = ("Bienvenido | " + str(time.strftime("%d")) + " de " + 
    str(time.strftime("%h")) + ", " + str(time.strftime("%Y")) + " " + 
    str(time.strftime("%H")) + ":" + str(time.strftime("%M")))
    timeText.config(text=timetext)

global window
window = Tk()
window.configure(bg="#000000")
window.geometry("1100x650")

timeText = Label(window, text=timetext, bg="black", fg="white", font= 
("Lato Black", 20))
timeText.pack()
timeText.place(x=10, y=2.5)

window.after(1000, updateTime)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Usa la funcion Tk.after(time,function);, para mas informacion:  https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/la-funcion-after-en-tkinter/

Comment: Probe esa funcion primero poniendo cualquier otra cosa, luego la probe poniendo lo que dice en la pregunta, pero no funciona, la hora se no se actualiza ¿Como hago?

Comment: ¿Puedo ver como usaste la funcion `after`?

Comment: Si, hago un edit

Comment: Ya hice el edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solucion**

Lo que habia que hacer es usar '.after(, )' que espera el  y luego ejecuta la

Comment: Intenta leer tu respuesta y despues lee la pregunta, veras que no soluciona el problema.